# Python : Sending SMTP HTML Email, but no pictures loaded

Tags: python, html, email

I'm trying to send a email from my python application.
I have a code which sends SMTP email with HTML code included. I have my HTML code in txt file which is working well if I would launch it on localhost as a page, all the pictures shows up. Also I have all the files in same directory. The format I need is like this:

[Normal format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QBKz.png)

[The format which I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxz1a.png)

This line is one of the images import in HTML

```
<!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr style="line-height:0px"><td style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;" align="center"><![endif]--><img align="center" alt="server" border="0" class="center fixedwidth" src="server.png" style="text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0; height: auto; width: 100%; max-width: 177px; display: block;" title="Image" width="177"/>

with open('messages.txt', mode = 'r' , encoding= 'UTF-8') as oap:
        z = oap.read()
    time.sleep(3)
    message.add_alternative(f"{z}", subtype = 'html')
```

With this code I open and read  the file, after its done I sent it through SMTP

> I also tried changing the picture location to this -
>   C:\Users\DzITC\Desktop\parking-app\server.png

After changing it in the web it does load the image, but in python no.

[Inspecting the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5dEU.png)

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the mail you sent.I had similar problem in php because google adds it's own content before image link given in mail

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When you inspect your image in the mail do you see the same path that you gave in src attribute of img tag?

Comment: no I do not see it, I did upload the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a filesystem path as the src of an img in an email won't work.  One way to include the image is to specify a content id as the src: `<img src="cid:some-id">`.  The content-id must conform to the specification in [rfc2392](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392): Python's email package can generate a conforming id.

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import make_msgid


html = """
<!-- example markup - add missing html, head, body etc tags -->
<p>Hello</p>
<!-- Use a format string place holder for the content id --> 
<img alt="My image" src="cid:{image_cid}"/>
"""

# Create a message
msg = EmailMessage()

# Create a content id for the image
image_cid = make_msgid()

# Add the html to the message, replacing the placeholder with the image id
# (the '<' and '>' characters at the start and end of the id must be stripped)
msg.add_alternative(html.format(image_cid=image_cid[1:-1], subtype='html'))

# Add the image to the message
with open('myimage.png', 'rb') as f:
    img = f.read()
    msg.add_related(img, 'image', 'png', cid=image_cid)
```

Comment: make_msg() should be make_msgid()